# Damaged site icons on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, chat, design, stackexchange.com

There are damaged site icons on chat.stackexchange.com popup:

> [image: icons]

Comment: That was happened somewhere earlier. Try a ctrl+f5 and you're done. This is fixed already